# Two Eyes Are Actually Open

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, rebus, poetry

*Apparently @[El-Guest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50778/el-guest) is good at solving rebus puzzles... oh, we'll see...*

---

Here is another rebus puzzle I drew... but a little different.

[image: REBUS]

Ugh, it is a bad photo. It has some stains on it, and  a shadow on the bottom left corner. Well, I can't keep *worrying* about it once it has *already* happened, right?

**Note:**

> The *real* answer is not what you might first think. The first person to find the word that is missing from the secret message will get a 50 rep bounty; explanations must also be required (including for the title).

---

**Hint 1:**

> the suffix is in the rebus.

**Hint 2:**

> Trails of sound is the key, 
>  With the wails quite especially. 
>  Although lines are important, 
>  If they are emboldened, 
>  None of the open can see.

**Hint 3:**

> A cry makes exactly what sound? 
>  There's another word! Can it be found? 
>  The thinnest points where? 
>  How many legs are there? 
>  One eye lies straight from what is round.

**Bonus:**

> To finish, rather ..., 
>  The tallest, you should first locate. 
>  Vertical, though across, 
>  Coming first without loss, 
>  Make a mixture, but not on this plate.

---

I have made a grammatical change **Hint 1**, but it does not affect its meaning at all; that is only for the added bonus. Whoever solves that with an explanation will receive a 100 rep bounty; I think that the main part of this puzzle is too hard and might need a 50 rep bounty).

Also, solving the bonus reveals one of the words in the secret message (that of which there are six); though if you are finding it too difficult, then the other hints should suffice.

Comment: Lotta arrows, I see.

Comment: @YoutRied hahah, yeah :P

Comment: Hmmm so it's not the obvious one, obviously. Let\s see

Comment: @R.D nah, my previous one was too obvious, so I checked out a bunch of rebus puzzles and decided to make one a bit harder. Everything is deliberately made (the stains, the shadow, and bold lines...)

Comment: @user477343 Yeah that I can understand. But this one I believe is above me. Either that or I do not know the proverb you are referring to

Comment: @R.D well I will tell you this: (ROT13) ybbx ng gur npebfgvpf va uvag 2. Gryy zr jung vg zrnaf, naq jung vg zvtug ersre gb. Vs lbh ner pbeerpg, lbh jvyy abgvpr vebal, naq gung'f jura gur svefg fragrapr fubhyq pbzr gb hfr... :P

Comment: @user477343 Gjnva? Vf vg ersreevat gb Gbz fnjlre?

Comment: @R.D Ab. Vg vf na nepunvp jbeq.

Comment: Hmm. I'll keep this for later use. My brain isn't working today

Comment: @R.D I'll add a hint later today. This one should really help once it's included :)

Comment: @user477343 Thinking of starting a bounty on this one? :)

Comment: @KevinL I will add one more hint... if nobody gets it, I will be putting up a bounty :D

Comment: Oh ok then :D @user477343

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the answer

> Double whammy ?

According to the hints

> A cry makes a "Waah" sound and the suffix is "Me" hence whammy

Also

> A double whammy means two bad things happening. One is the character has spilled his milk and the second one is you "spilling" water on the drawing.
>  The italicized words "worry", "already", "real" (now this may be a stretch) but perhaps it's telling you to let bygones be bygones yet the irony is that the character is still crying over the milk?

Will wait for more hints or some confirmation of at least some part of this solution.

Edit:

After much discussion, the answer is

> Wait until the cows come home. 
>  Since i am at work right now, i cant type much so will explain later. Unless op explains it. Also the missing word is either "come" or "home"

Reasons:

> Look carefully at the arms, you will see the left arm + chin are bold and resembles a T.
> Now look at the throat, it is bold as well and looks like an I. Two eyes (I's) are open and we already have one of them. The other I is on the side of the milk carton, look at the thick arrow pointing downward, the I is just above it.
> Now it comes to the crying stick figure. A crying sound makes a "Waa" so Waa+I+T = "Wait". The cow on the carton is also a hint to what we should wait for. And the last part, suffix has "ME" in it (It is literally there in the rebus). So we have the proverb "Wait until the cows come home". Also it might be just me but if you look at the head of the carton sideways, it somewhat resembles a cartoon house that you can easily draw.

Comment: The answer is wrong, but you got the first part correct! i.e. for Hint 3, you have answered the first question correct! :P

Comment: Hmmm. I will be needing a few more hints though. Tell me, is it a proverb that you are using?

Comment: Do you mean the missing word from the secret message, or  the message's first word?

Comment: @user477343 The message itself. Rot13(Ol gur jnl, vf gurer nal jrncba vaibyirq urer? Fnl n favcre? )

Comment: Hahah, I didn't know what a proverb was; I thought it was just another certain type of word (like "adverb"). Doing some research now, yes, the message is a proverb (not related to snipers). I mean, I know of many proverbs, but didn't know they were *called* proverbs :)

Comment: Hmmmmmm. Still not sure how twain comes into play here

Comment: Rot13(Gjnva = gjb, pbeerpg. Va gur gvgyr, gurer ner gjb rlrf gung ner bcra. Va gur uvag, gur jbeq "gjnva" ersref gb ubj jung vf "bcra" (fb gung ersref gb gur rlrf). Ohg vs rlrf ner bcra, ubj pna gurl abg frr? Jryy, znlor, gurl ner abg rlrf... ohg gurve anzr fbhaqf yvxr "rlrf". Pna lbh svaq gjb fhpu "rlrf" va gur erohf?) :D

Comment: @user477343 pevrf naq qevrf?

Comment: Ab, gung vf abg pbeerpg. Gur bayl pelvat cneg pbagnvarq va gur frperg cebireo vf gur fbhaq bs gur pel... naq gura vg tbrf ba gb vapyhqr n pbj, shaavyl rabhtu... abobql unf zragvbarq gur pbj :Q

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82653/discussion-between-r-d-and-user477343).

Comment: The update is correct. Now just for the explanations. But I'll spare you, since you explained and figured it out in the chat. Just explain what the missing word of the proverb is (the word that is supposed to be in the rebus to make the proverb, but isn't), and then you will get the tick :D

Comment: @user477343 Done, you should really change your username to "Sneaky Devil" XD

Comment: Maybe I should have waited for the bounty Xd

Comment: @user477343 Do i need to edit this to make it a more acceptable answer?

Comment: yes, but only for one last part: the missing word! You noticed the same thing as @ShahriarMahmudSajid did in your reasoning section, which was unintended, but very interesting. However, you noticed something else that will find the missing word! Can you find it? We'll **see**... (that first line not part of my rebus might be a hint for this particular part... I mean, it is in italics, right?).

Comment: We'll see or in this case , we'll c ? C as in come? @user477343

Comment: You got it! But... that's not the missing word, for that has been explained in the rebus. (I'm sure you'll find it now, with the I and arrow and small black O and ME)... That leaves just one word left..

Comment: @user477343 Home?

Comment: Yes! But... how come? (I am in a pun-like mood, today, for some reason.) :P

Comment: Oh we never got to this one did we? Spare me the trouble please :P Also the water droplets on the paper are just red herrings aren't they? @user477343

Comment: Hahah, it's fine. The water droplets can be a red herring (because it resembles the tears) but it was mainly just for something extra. All you need to focus on is that top part of the carton. It should be enough to show the word "come". I now need to have a shower and will most likely not get back on because it's hitting about $10$:$30$pm here in my country, so I need to go to sleep. I will check back on this in the morning :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82865/discussion-between-r-d-and-user477343).

Comment: Alright, I talked more about it in the chat. Sorry I did not reply earlier. Congratulations! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ DVL11

Comment: Oof. That was a bit too obscure for me XD Thanks though

Comment: Hahah, the three italic words (*worrying*, *already* and *real*) are a hint: *worrying* is a hint (because it refers to the sound of crying), and the words *already* and *real* have two "eyes" with one eye each (namely, **l**) :D

Answer (score 2):

I think the actual answer is

> There's no use crying over spilt milk.

Reasoning

> The *crying over spilt milk* part has already been addressed by Shahriar. The crucial miss part is *There's no use*. There are two clues pointing to this. First, there is no **you** in the picture, only **me**. Also the title says that the "Two Eyes are Actually Open" but we don't observe this as there is no U-shape completing the curve of the eyes i.e, *There's no **U**s"*

Comment: That is a good try, but unfortunately not the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is:

> Why me!
>
>  The suffix is in the rebus - that's the "me" part
>  There are emboldened lines picturing the body and the arms that form the letter "Y" which is equal to "Why" 
>  Also saying "why" starts with "whaaa" which is pretty much wailing.

Comment: @user477343 Anywhere close?

Comment: That is not the answer, but you are looking in the right area! The emboldened lines are definitely important, and sorry for not replying sooner. (I was away on school camp.) You also nailed the crying part, so good job on that, and you have also linked the two in the correct fashion. Perhaps instead of seeing a Y, maybe look for d**i**fferen**t** letters (sometimes you need to look closely to see the *bigger picture*) :P

Answer (score 2):

Ok maybe I've been looking at this too long but I'm seeing quite a lot in this rhebus.

In addition to the obvious proverb about crying over spilt milk

> 1. Woe is me

Because of

> The wah sound for cry but with an O made from the head

And the

> I comes from the left closed eye on the milk carton. If you look at it sideways, it looks like a face with one eye open and one shut (more later) and with a squiggle for a mouth. The mouth can either be an s or a 5. The me comes from the actual me

2. Next  I think

> There is the phrase sleeping with one eye open because of the face on the milk carton.

3. This is more nebulous but I think the idea of

> A black cloud hanging over me

because of

> Something that looks like a black cloud above the person's head

4. Also, I haven't made it out yet, but I see the following

> Let ters

Such as

> S shape in whole of the tongue

And

> 2 Ls or 2 7s inside the tongue

And

> W from the eyes of the main face because the eyes look like Us upside down and two of them = double U

And

> There also appears to be a large X in the right hand side of the figure

And

> There also send to be a face in the upper left that looks like Mao but I'm going to chalk this up to sleep dep lol.

So in summary, I'm seeing those phrases and these

> Letters W L L X S I S

As well as lots of other

> Letters if I really squint, including a C

So if we flip the

> W upside down we could get an M which is a Roman numeral along with L, X, I, and S if we interpret as 5 and convert to V.

I'm not totally positive but there could be another phrase:

> 20,000 leagues under the sea? And maybe even sleeping with the fishes?

Am I close with any of this??

Addition/Edit:

Also it occurs to me that the title refers to the eyes on the

> Bull on the milk carton both of which are open

I think one of the hidden sayings is either

> Sitting Bull

Or

> Bullseye

Comment: That is a remarkable effort. I understand the third spoiler perfectly well, so no need to touch up on that later if you don't have to; and after reading that, I'm never gonna look at my drawing the same ever again, haha. But unfortunately, none of the proverbs are correct. The closest one is the first one you proposed (the "waa" sound is correct; the S is in the right spot (being at the *end* of a word); and the intended proverb definitely ends with a me (though not in the way your first-proposed proverb does. This is a hint, which might even extend on Hint 1.)). But overall, brilliant answer!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe -

> Crying over spilled milk

Some notes:

> Noticed three italic words below the rebus *worrying*, *already* & *real*, maybe they are a clue towards the message you are looking for, need some more work to figure out what it is.

More notes

> acrostic of Hint2 spells out twain, which is an archaic word for two. crying sounds can be wail, whimper, sob or weep. not sure which one is intended yet.

Final Touches:

> it is found in the discussion that the answer is- 
>  Wait until the cows come home. 
>  So the word in the bonus hint is -wait (to finish , rather wait...)
>  The two eyes in the title refers to two I's in the pic, one in the emboldened part of the body, one above the down pointing arrow
>  the missing word is either come or home, since it ends with me, though i would say it is come, because the upper part of the milk carton looks to me like a drawing of a house(i.e. home) like i used to draw when i was a kid. so the only word missing is come.
> the explanation of the actual message is-wa(crying sound)+It (the emboldened parts spell -it)
> up+2(thinnest arrows point up and number of legs 2)synonym of up to is until.
> picture of cow + letters S beside the down arrow makes cows 
>  giving us -wait until the cows,
> and the- come home part was a nice guess work from R.D

Comment: Nope. That's not it. It's not what you first think. I mean, you are right... but to a certain extent... thus you are not receiving the bounty with this answer :D

Comment: Also, the italic notes are definitely the clues (to both answers actually: yours and the intended answer!) :D

Comment: Maybe rot13(_jbeevat nyernql erny?_)

Comment: @u_ndefined nope, that is not it.

Comment: When I say crying sounds, think of actual sounds. If I was crying, I wouldn't be saying "wail", would I? :P

Comment: The word in the bonus is not that. In fact, it is three words. (You got one of them correct, though, and the words literally mean the same thing as "wait" anyways.) Also, the missing word isn't right, either... so now the real missing word is *definitely* confirmed.... all yu need to figure out is why (though the top of the carton *does* look like the roof of a house, oddly enough) :P

Answer (score 1):

Hmm a tricky rebus!

A possible answer would be

> Bottom's Up! The bottom of the milk carton has an arrow pointing up :)

If not, the suffix may be

> ME. After all, it is in the rebus!

By the way, nice touch on the stains!

Comment: No. Good attempt, but unfortunately not the answer. And also, thank you! The stains were a little difficult to make (because too much water would have ruined it) :P **Hint:** Think about *where* the arrow is pointing up! (And if you didn't notice, there is an arrow pointing downwards, too).

Comment: Oh, and yes, you got the suffix correct. I apologise if my above comment thus proved to be misleading...